# Two dataframes broadcast together in multiple subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot 5 different subplots, one for each year of data.  For each year, I want to show the DEMs and REPs for each county.  I have written the following code so far:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,10))

plt.subplot(3, 2, 1)
plt.bar(data=districts_2018[['DEM', 'REP']], 
        x=districts_2018.index, 
        height=(districts_2018[['DEM', 'REP']]))

plt.subplot(3, 2, 2)
plt.bar(data=districts_2017[['DEM', 'REP']], 
        x=districts_2017.index, 
        height=districts_2017['DEM'])

plt.subplot(3, 2, 3)
plt.bar(data=districts_2016[['DEM', 'REP']], 
        x=districts_2016.index, 
        height=districts_2016['DEM'])

plt.subplot(3, 2, 4)
plt.bar(data=districts_2015[['DEM', 'REP']], 
        x=districts_2015.index, 
        height=districts_2015['DEM'])

plt.subplot(3, 2, 5)
plt.bar(data=districts_2014[['DEM', 'REP']], 
        x=districts_2014.index, 
        height=districts_2014['DEM'])

plt.tight_layout();
```

However, as in the case of the first subplot (3,2,1) I get the error: 
`ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`.  This code works if I only set the height to `districts_2018['DEM']` but then that only shows the DEMs and not the REPs.

Comment: The order of arguments in `plt.bar` seems to be wrong. A per [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), the first argument is `x`, followed by `height` and then `width`. Try **printing** districts_2016['DEM']` and see how it is different from `districts_2018[['DEM', 'REP']]`

Comment: ok i took out data and now just have: ```plt.subplot(3, 2, 1)
plt.bar(x=districts_2018.index, 
        height=(districts_2018[['DEM', 'REP']]))``` but still getting the error: ```shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape```

Comment: Try printing the different heights to check the shape

Comment: `bar` can only plot a single sequence of data, which is why `height=districts_2018['DEM']` works as expected. If you want to plot two sequences, you need to call `bar` twice.

Comment: ok so i called bar twice like this: ```plt.subplot(3, 2, 1)
plt.bar(data=districts_2018['DEM'],
       x=districts_2018.index,
       height=districts_2018['DEM'])

plt.bar(data=districts_2018['REP'],
       x=districts_2018.index,
       height=districts_2018['REP'])``` but now it plots with the bars on top of each other - I want them side by side to show difference in height

Comment: Sure, in order to have them non-overlapping you would need to use a different x value. In general it looks like you would be better off directly using the pandas plotting wrapper like `districts_2018[['DEM', 'REP']].plot.bar()`.

Comment: yes, I tried that too like this: ```plt.subplot(3, 2, 1)
districts_2018[['DEM', 'REP']].plot(kind='bar',
                                   color=['xkcd:blue',
                                         'xkcd:red'])
plt.xlabel('District', fontsize=17)
plt.ylabel('Number of Registered Voters', fontsize=17)
plt.title('2018', fontsize=20)``` and while it did plot the two columns side by side like i wanted, I then ran into broadcasting issues with my subplots where it broadcast 5 blank plots and only the last one in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may directly use the pandas wrapper to plot grouped bar plots. Set the `ax` to the respective subplot you want the plot to appear in.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,2,figsize=(13,10))
for ax, df in zip(axes.flat, [districts_2018, districts_2017, ....])
    df[['DEM', 'REP']].plot.bar(ax=ax)
```